# What does "Box<Fn() + Send + 'static>" mean in rust?

Tags: types, rust, traits, lifetime, lifetime-scoping

What does `Box<Fn() + Send + 'static>` mean in rust?

I stumbled upon this syntax while reading advanced types chapter. `Send` is a trait but what does it mean to `+` a lifetime to a trait (`'static` in this case) in type parametrization ? Also what is `Fn()` ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Let's decompose it one-by-one.

## Box

`Box<T>` is a pointer to heap-allocated `T`. We use it here because trait objects can only exist behind pointers.

## Trait objects

In `Box<Fn() + Send + 'static>`, `Fn() + Send + 'static` is a [*trait object*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) type. In future, it will be [written `Box<dyn (Fn() + Send + 'static)>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2113-dyn-trait-syntax.md) to avoid confusion.

Inside `dyn` are restrictions to the original type. **`Box<T>` can be coerced into `Box<Fn() + Send + 'static>` only when `T: Fn() + Send + 'static`**. Therefore, although we don't know the original type, we can assume it was `Fn()` and `Send` and **had `'static` lifetime**.

## `Fn()`

This is a trait, just like `Clone` or `Default`. However, it uses a special *syntax sugar*.

- `Fn(A1, ..., An)` is a syntax sugar for `Fn<(A1, ..., An), Output=()>`.
- `Fn(A1, ..., An) -> R` is a syntax sugar for `Fn<(A1, ..., An), Output=R>`.
- This syntax sugar also applies to the following traits: [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html), and [`FnBox`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html).

So what does `Fn` mean? `T: Fn(A1, ..., An) -> R` means `x: T` is a callable object with arguments `A1, ..., An` and return type `R`. Examples include function pointers and closures.

## Send

[`Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) means that values of this type can be sent across threads. Since this is an [auto trait](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0019-opt-in-builtin-traits.md), it [can be specified as the second bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/45772) of `dyn` types (trait object types).

## `'static` bound

In fact, **`dyn` types (trait object types) must have exactly one lifetime bound**. It's inferred when omitted. The inference rule is described in [RFC 0192](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0192-bounds-on-object-and-generic-types.md) and [RFC 1156](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1156-adjust-default-object-bounds.md). It's basically as follows:

1. If explicitly given, use that lifetime.
2. Otherwise, it is inferred from the inner trait. For example, `Box<Any>` is `Box<Any + 'static>` because [`Any: 'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html).
3. If the trait doesn't have an appropriate lifetime, it is inferred from the outer type. For example, `&'a Fn()` is `&'a (Fn() + 'a)`.
4. If that even failed, it falls back to `'static` (for a function signature) or an anonymous lifetime (for a function body).

## Conclusion

`f: Box<Fn() + Send + 'static>` is an owned pointer to a callable value (with the original type unknown and dynamically change) such as closures (with no argument or no return value), which can be sent across threads and lives as long as the program itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Masaki for the detailed explanation!  One off-topic question:   Does `Box<&i32>` mean that it will allocate the pointer/reference in the `heap` and that the `borrowed content (i32)` (the data it is pointing to) could well be on stack? and that `*b` will give me `&i32` and `**b` will give 100 (given that `let m = 100; let b:Box<&i32> = Box::new(&m);`); Not considering `println!` here which `autorefs`

Comment: @soupybionics I know you may not care by now lol, but I believe so. There's not much reason to box a reference to a stack-allocated value, of course, and you wouldn't be able to do much with the box since it would be invalid after the i32 gets dropped or moved.

Comment: @HutchMoore, yes it was more of a hypothetical question.

Answer (score 8):

I found the `'static` part needs more elaboration from [the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018183/5335565).

Denote the **underlying concrete** type as `A`.

Trait object `Box<dyn Fn() + Send + 'static>` can be constructed from an instance of `A`, which implies `A: Fn() + Send + 'static`. That is to say, the concrete type `A` is bounded by `static` lifetime.

specific [explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html#trait-bound) for `'static` as trait bound:

> As a trait bound, it means the type does not contain any non-static references. Eg. the receiver can hold on to the type for as long as they want and it will never become invalid until they drop it.
>
> It's important to understand this means that any owned data always passes a `'static` lifetime bound, but a reference to that owned data generally does not

A [generative explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds) for cases where any lifetime is used as trait bound:

> T: 'a means that **all lifetime parameters of T outlive 'a**. For example if 'a is an unconstrained lifetime parameter then i32: 'static and &'static str: 'a are satisfied but Vec<&'a ()>: 'static is not.

For our case, all lifetime parameters of `A` must outlive `'static`, for example

```rust
pub struct A<'a> {
   buf: &'a[u8]
}
```

can't meet `A: 'static` requirement.

Comment: So is a 'static lifetime a bad thing? If I overuse it does it mean they'll never get released? Or is rust smart enough to even on 'static lifetimes to release the object/reference if it's not being used anymore?

Comment: @RafaelMerlin it's not bad at all. if it's under reference context, it means to live the entire program lifetime. You can also use Box to intentionally `leak` heap memory. Having full control of the underlying memory life cycle is a good thing. If you decide to overuse it, you need to bear the outcome. I think that's fair.