# *mut (dyn std::ops::Fn() + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely with serde::de::DeserializeOwned struct

Tags: rust, async-await, serde, reqwest

I'm attempting to use [Iced (UI framework based on The Elm Architecture)](https://github.com/hecrj/iced/) with [Reqwest (wrapper over hyper)](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/) which can use [Serde for JSON deserialisation](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde).

Independently they work correctly, but I'm new to Rust and something about my implementation is wrong.

I start with an (in-progress) networking function.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub(crate) enum Error {
    APIError,
    ParseError,
}

impl From<reqwest::Error> for Error {
    fn from(error: reqwest::Error) -> Self {
        Error::APIError
    }
}

pub(crate) async fn post<T>(request: Request) -> Result<T, Error>
where
    T: DeserializeOwned + Debug + Clone,
{
    let headers = standard_headers(request.params);
    let response = Client::new()
        .post(&format!("{}{}", request.base, request.path))
        .json(&request.body)
        .headers(headers)
        .send()
        .await?
        .json::<T>()
        .await?;

    Ok(response)
}
```

and I attempt to use it as part of Iced:

```
fn new() -> (Runner, Command<Message>) {
    (
        Runner::Loading,
        Command::perform(post(Login::request()), Message::Next),
    )
}
```

and I receive the compile error of:

```
error[E0277]: `*mut (dyn std::ops::Fn() + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/feature/runner/runner.rs:42:13
   |
42 |             Command::perform(post(Login::request()), Message::Next),
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*mut (dyn std::ops::Fn() + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
   | 
  ::: <snip>/futures/src/command/native.rs:29:22
   |
29 |         future: impl Future<Output = T> + 'static + Send,
   |                      ------------------ required by this bound in `iced_futures::command::native::Command::<T>::perform`
   |
   = help: within `core::fmt::Void`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `*mut (dyn std::ops::Fn() + 'static)`
```

I believe the problem relates to using [T: DeserializeOwned and life times](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html) in the `post`, whereby the ownership is such that the `T` type in the `async fn post` might be on a different thread to an async call within Command (hence the mention of `Send`.

The answer may even be in the lifetime link, but I don't have enough knowledge yet to see it or to know if i'm in the right place with my thinking. I debugged back to just using a concrete type instead of `T` which works.

I'd love to understand why this problem exists and what I can do to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017290/what-does-boxfn-send-static-mean-in-rust

Answer (score 0):

This hint:

```
help: within `core::fmt::Void`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `*mut (dyn std::ops::Fn() + 'static)`
```

makes me think that this whole issue is related to your use of `format!` within `fn post` (see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64960). Try upgrading your rust compiler or moving the url out before the long `.await` chain:

```rust
let url = format!("{}{}", request.base, request.path);
let response = Client::new()
    .post(&url)
    // ...
```